# Extrapolate bell shape from a section of curve

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, gaussian, normal-distribution

I am interested in extrapolating the curve from the population that I know is normally distributed. However, in my process, I am only able to get access to a section of the curve (from -3 standard deviations to -2 standard deviations). My question is what is the best way to fitting a curve to a section of a bell curve.

Comment: Would yiu please post a link to the data, or possibly add it to the post?

Comment: Do you know the size of the population? That would put some restrictions to a fit.

Answer (score 0):

A normal distribution can be defined by an equation `f(x)` (its PDF, which is a little difficult to write in non-latex, you can check out [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)) with two parameters: the mean and the variance (or standard deviation).

Therefore, if you want to know *which* variance and mean define it, you just need to solve for the mean and the variance given two known values (which you have infinitely many of, even on a short interval).

Comment: Or try curve fitting the data using scipy's differential_evolution genetic algorithm to give initial parameter estimates, which is why I requested the data - so I could see how well that technique would work in this case.